# Чем отличается отладчик от дизассемблера

Tags: отладка, дизассемблирование

Всем доброго! Вот я тут задался вопросом чем отличается отладчик от дизассемблера. Раньше я, вроде как, понимал в чём разница, но теперь запутался

[Дизассемблер вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80)

[Отладчик вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Вроде разница есть, судя по ссылка на вики, но OllyDbg это тоже отладчик, хотя он выдаёт ассемблерный код программы и его можно менять, как и в дизассемблере. Тут вот я и запутался. Подскажете в чём разница и что лучше для анализа программ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Любой нормальный отладчик должен содержать в себе хотя бы примитивный дизассемблер.  Хотя раньше существовали отладчики, которые позволяли только в бинарных кодах отлаживать. В этом случае дизассемблировать комманду нужно было самостоятиельно (в голове или на листике).

Нормальный дизассемблер отладчик не обязан содержать. Но если хочется разбираться с самомодифицирущим кодом, то тут обычно без отладчика никак.

Какая же между ними разница? Задача дизассемблера не просто перевести бинарный код в ассемблерный, а и провести дополнительный анализ (хотя бы минимальный). Задача отладчика - быстро выполнять отлаживаемую программу, связывать ее с языком высокого уровня (при этом программист может даже не знать о том, что там бинарный код) и минимально определятся отлаживаемой программой.

Что же лучше для анализа? и то, и другое, но самое главное - мозг и листик с карандашом.

Answer (score 1):

Отладчик позволяет отлаживать программу, дизасм - нет. Отладчик применяется для динамического исследования, дизасм - для статического, поэтому нет никакого "лучше", как правило их необходимо применять совместно.